# Office 365 Unified API beta/me/photo Unauthorized

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

Since some days I'm not able to get the LogedIn User Photo. I always get an StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'.

That's the API url I access: https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/photos('96x96')/$value

The changes from the Update 3 are applied.

The Permissions: "Sign in and read user profile (Office 365 unified API)" are given.

This worked well for me but now there is this problem. Is there a known issue? Would be nice if somebody can give me some hints ore a alternative way to get the User Profile Picture.

I develop a ASP.NET MVC Multitenant App that access the Office 365 API like SharePoint and Outlook.

Comment: Is https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/photo/$value returning the same error?
Can you please list all permissions that your app is asking for?

Comment: https://outlook.office.com/beta/me/photo/$value => Not Found

Comment: https://outlook.office.com/api/beta/me/photo/$value =>  StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized'

Comment: My permissions are: Access the directory as you (AAD), Sign you in and read you profile (AAD), Sign in and read your profile (Office 365 unified)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need other permissions.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) says you'll need the `Read all users' full profiles` permission (which is under the Application Permissions).

You also have to grant these permissions, which can only be done by an Azure AD admin.